# Field extensions - if $(E : F) = n$ then $(E(x) : F(x)) = n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Well, pretty much everything is in the title - I'm looking for the proof of the following statement: if we have a field extension $F \subset E$ then the degree of the extension $F(x) \subset E(x)$ [fields of rational functions] is the same as that of $E$ over $F$. Will be grateful for any hints!

Comment: If $v_1, ... , v_n$ is a basis for $E/F$, then it is also a basis for $E(x)/F(x)$.

Comment: I don't really see that - it's easy for polynomials, but we're dealing with rational functions. could you give some details?

Comment: If you are interested in the finite extension case, I recently wrote an elementary proof here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/758014/kafa-kf-if-a-is-transcendental-over-k/758116#758116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a continuation of the other answer I wrote; we'll show that $v_1, ... , v_n$ is a spanning set.  I am not sure whether giving an explicit formula for how to write an arbitrary member of $E(X)$ as an $F(X)$-linear combination of the $v_i$ is possible, unless more is known about the basis elements $v_i$.

Here is a "proof by shenanigans."  We know that $E = F[v_1, ... , v_n]$.  So $$E(X) = F[v_1, ... , v_n](X)$$  We want to first of all show this is equal to $$F(X)[v_1, ... , v_n]$$ Now, the first set I've written is by definition a field, and a subset of every field which contains $F[v_1, ... , v_n]$ and $X$ (it is the "smallest" such field).  The second set is by definition a ring, and contained in every ring which contains $F(X)$ and $v_1, ... , v_n$ (it is the "smallest" such ring).

It's clear that the second set is contained in the first.  That the first set is contained in the second follows from the fact that $F(X)[v_1, ... , v_n]$ is a field (a field adjoined with any number of algebraic elements remains a field).

So $E(X)$ is equal to $F(X)$ adjoined with the elements $v_1, ... , v_n$.  Thus an arbitrary member of $E(X)$ is equal to a finite sum $\sum\limits_i \frac{f_i(X)}{g_i(X)} v_1^{n_{i_1}} \cdots v_n^{n_{i_n}}$, for $n_{i_j} \geq 0$ and $\frac{f_i(X)}{g_i(X)} \in F(X)$.  But we are now done, because each product $v_1^{i_1} \cdots v_n^{i_n}$ is equal to an $F$-linear combination of $v_1, ... , v_n$.

Comment: nice, thanks for taking the time to complete the answer, that helps a lot!

Comment: you're welcome!

Answer (score 5):

You could prove this by proving that the natural $F(x)$-algebra map $E\otimes_FF(x)\to E(x)$ is an isomorphism. This is not a trivial thing in the sense that, if $E/F$ were transcendental, this map would not be an isomorphism (indeed if $E=F(x)$ itself, for example, then the tensor product $F(x)\otimes_FF(x)$ is not a field). Anyway, first note that $E\otimes_FF(x)=(E\otimes_FF[x])\otimes_{F[x]}F(x)=E[x]\otimes_{F[x]}F(x)$. This is a localization of the domain $E[x]$, hence a domain, and it is also a finite-dimensional $F(x)$-algebra. Such a ring (a domain of finite dimension over a field) must be a field. Ring maps out of fields are injective.

So $E\otimes_FF(x)=E[x]\otimes_{F[x]}F(x)\to E(x)$ is an injective map whose image is a subfield of $E(x)$ containing $E[x]$ (since $E[x]\otimes_{F[x]}F(x)$ contains $E[x]$ via $f(x)\mapsto f(x)\otimes 1$, and this is mapped to $f(x)\in E(x)$). It follows that the image contain all of, and hence equals, $E(x)$.

So we have an $F(x)$-algebra (and in particular an $F(x)$-linear) isomorphism $E\otimes_FF(x)\simeq E(x)$. The tensor product visibly has dimension over $F(x)$ equal to $[E:F]$.

This argument works more generally if $E/F$ is algebraic. In deducing that $E[x]\otimes_{F[x]}F(x)$ was a field because it was a domain of finite dimension over a field, it would have been enough to know that it was integral over a field, and this will be true if $E/F$ is algebraic.

As I alluded to above, if $E/F$ is not algebraic, this map can't be injective. Namely, we can reduce to $E=F(x)$, and in this case, $x\otimes 1-1\otimes x$ is a non-zero element of the kernel of $E\otimes_FF(x)\to E(x)$.

Comment: looks quite sophisticated, but I'll try to understand it, thanks a lot!

Comment: This is an excellent answer: +1.

Comment: Dear @Georges, Thank you! As I've said before, that means a lot coming from you!

Comment: wanted to thank you again for your input - I'm pretty sure (seeing the votes and the comments) that your answer is an excellent one. nevertheless I'm a newbie in algebra and it's quite hard for me to digest what you wrote, so I'm gonna accept the easier (for me) answer, hope you don't mind. already upvoted yours of course!

Answer (score 0):

Let $v_1, ... , v_n \in E$ be a basis for $E/F$.  First let's show these elements are linearly independent over $F(X)$.  Suppose $$\frac{f_1(X)}{g_1(X)}v_1 + \cdots + \frac{f_n(X)}{g_n(X)}v_n = 0$$ where $f_i(X)$ and $0 \neq g_i(X)$ are in $ F[X]$.  Let $G(X) = g_1(X) \cdots g_n(X)$, and $h_i(X) = \frac{G(X)}{g_i(X)} = g_1(X) \cdots g_{i-1}(X)g_{i+1}(X)$.  Multiply both sides of the above equation by $G(X)$ to get $$h_1(X)v_1 + \cdots + h_n(X)v_n = 0$$ By pairing up the coefficients belonging to the terms $1, X, X^2$ etc. its easy to see that the coefficients of each polynomial $h_i(X)$ are all $0$.

Therefore $0 = f_i(X)g_1(X) \cdots g_{i-1}(X)g_{i+1}(X) \cdots g_n(X)$, which implies $f_i(X) = 0$ because none of the polynomials $g_i(X)$ are $0$.

I'll leave it to you to show that $v_1, ... , v_n$ span $E(X)/F(X)$.

Comment: I still can't see how the spanning part would go, could you perhaps give a sketch of the reasoning or an example of finding appropriate representation?

Comment: This is perhaps a little trickier than I initially thought.  I will think on this matter.

Comment: See my second answer.