# If a field $F$ is an algebraic extension of a field $K$ then $(F:K)=(F(x):K(x))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> Suppose $K$ is a field and $F$ is an algebraic extension of some degree $n=(F:K)$. It is stated that the field of rational functions $F(x)$ is in fact an algebraic extension of the field $K(x)$ and moreover $(F(x):K(x))=n$.

How do I approach this exercise? I'm new in this area so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "Field of rational function", it does mean anything in the context... Do you mean $F(x)=\{f:\mathbb Q\longrightarrow \mathbb R\}$ ?it looks very strange. Or $F(x)\in \mathbb Q$ ?

Comment: @MSE It means the quotient field of $F[x]$ or all elements $p(x)/q(x)$ with $p,q\in F[x]$. ($q\neq 0$)

Comment: This is true in general: if $F$ is an arbitrary field extension of $K$ (not necessarily finite or algebraic) and $x$ is transcendental over $F$, then $[F:K]=\big[F(x),K(x)\big]$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does $K \leadsto K(X)$ preserve the degree of field extensions?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4581/why-does-k-leadsto-kx-preserve-the-degree-of-field-extensions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ be a basis for $F$ over $K$. Let's first show that they are linearly independent as elements of $F(x)$ over $K(x)$. So assume
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\frac{f_i(x)}{g(x)}=0
$$
where $f_1,\dots,f_n,g\in K[x]$ (it's not restrictive to assume the denominators are the same). This implies
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_if_i(x)=0
$$
If we have $f_i(x)=\sum_{j=0}^k b_{ij}x^j$, we deduce
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_{ij}=0,\quad j=0,1,\dots,k
$$
so all polynomials are $0$.

Now the task is to show that $F(x)=K(x)[a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n]$ and we can reduce this to showing that, if $a$ is algebraic over $K$, then
$$
K[a](x)=K(x)[a]
$$
One inclusion is obvious, namely $K(x)[a]\subseteq K[a](x)$. In order to show the converse inclusion we just need to prove that if $f(x)\in K[a](x)$, then $f(x)\in K(x)[a]$, because the latter is a field. This is trivial, by considering polynomials of the form $cx^m$, where $c\in K[a]$. Just write $c=d_0+d_1a+\dots+d_ra^r$, where $r+1$ is the degree of $a$ over $K$ and then $cx^m=\sum_{j=0}^r a^j(d_jx^m)\in K(x)[a]$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! One thing I don't understand: why in the end for the converse inclusion we consider only polynomials? You showed that $cx^m$ for $c\in K[a]$ lies in $K(x)[a]$. But what about other polynomials and rational functions from $K[a](x)$? Why they are in $K(x)[a]$?

Comment: @Glinka If we show that all polynomials in $K[a](x)$ belong to $K(x)[a]$, then also fractions will, because $K(x)[a]$ is a field. For polynomials it's the same: once all monomials $cx^m\in K(x)[a]$, also sums of monomials belong to $K(x)[a]$.

Comment: yes, of course, got it!